# I can't get specific data from Firebase (Java)

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm doing an application where I need to go in my firebase to get Latitude and Longitude. I don't have any problem to put the Latlng in firebase but i can't get it back. this is what it looks like :

[image: my firebase].

And this is the code when I put them in firebase

```
Ajouter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mProgress.setTitle("Le point se charge");
            mProgress.setMessage("Merci de patientez, ce ne sera pas long");
            mProgress.show();
            mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
            FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
            mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            mMarkDatabase = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
            final String key = mMarkDatabase.child("Pins").push().getKey();

            final StorageReference ref = mStorage.child("Photos/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();
            UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putBytes(data);
            uploadTask = ref.putFile(ImageUri);
            Task<Uri> urltask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }

                    return ref.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                        downloadUrl = task.getResult();
                        downloadUrlTxt = downloadUrl.toString();

                        //uploadImage();
                        String lon = Double.toString(Longitude);
                        String lat = Double.toString(Latitude);
                        String txt = TxtAout.getText().toString();
                        switch (spinner.getSelectedItemPosition()){
                            case 0 :
                                item.put("ImageUrl", ""+downloadUrlTxt);
                                item.put("Longitude ", lon);
                                item.put("Latitude", lat);
                                item.put("Description", txt);
                                mMarkDatabase.child("Pins").child("Poubelle").child(key).setValue(item);
                                break;
                            case 1 :
                                item.put("ImageUrl", ""+downloadUrlTxt);
                                item.put("Longitude ", lon);
                                item.put("Latitude", lat);
                                item.put("Description", txt);
                                mMarkDatabase.child("Pins").child("BlueLy").child(key).setValue(item);
                                break;
                            case 2 :
                                item.put("ImageUrl", ""+downloadUrlTxt);
                                item.put("Longitude ", lon);
                                item.put("Latitude", lat);
                                item.put("Description", txt);
                                mMarkDatabase.child("Pins").child("Parcs a chiens").child(key).setValue(item);
                                break;
                            case 3 :
                                item.put("ImageUrl", ""+downloadUrlTxt);
                                item.put("Longitude ", lon);
                                item.put("Latitude", lat);
                                item.put("Description", txt);
                                mMarkDatabase.child("Pins").child("Collecte de vetements").child(key).setValue(item);
                                break;
                            default :
                                Toast.makeText(LocalisationOnlyVert.this, "Erreur, merci de recommencer", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                        mProgress.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(LocalisationOnlyVert.this, "Merci de votre ajout !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        TxtAout.setText("");
                        Intent Retour = new Intent (LocalisationOnlyVert.this, OnlyVert.class);
                        startActivity(Retour);
                        Toast.makeText(LocalisationOnlyVert.this, ""+downloadUrlTxt , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

I don't know how to separate my latitude, my longitude, description and URL. I don't know what to do anymore.

Edit : After what you send me i tried :

```
BtnMarker.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
            mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                        HandleData.Pin pin = snapshot.getValue(HandleData.Pin.class);
                        Toast.makeText(OnlyVert.this, pin.getLat(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }


                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
}
```

The mistake is `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class com.example.alexandre.onlyvert.HandleData$Pin does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.`

Comment: Post code instead of pictures

Comment: what code you are using  to fetch the data ?

Comment: Yes i'm sorry it's done

Comment: problem resolved?

Comment: I have tried a couple of things but nothing seems to work as i want. Do you have an idea of what's best to get them ?

Comment: ok,  just tell what actually you are trying to do so that i can understand what you want

Comment: okay so , the user can add LatLng in the firebase, i want to get them back to show Pins at the LatLng but don't know how to get them

Comment: Can you translate the error line in your Firebase Database image to English. Also, avoid putting your firebase url in image, it can be misused.

Comment: @Alexandre that i understood but i cant understand those names, what they suggest and what their meaning is can you please tell your intention. i mean i know you have put data inside database which might also be not in right manner so please tell your aim what you want to acomplish

Comment: why you Longitude key at your Firebase is with " " ?

Answer (score 0):

Use this following class it has got everything you want

you can set data using this and track events too

you can get data using this and again track the events

```
 public class HandleData {

    private OnDataSet onDataSet;
    private OnDataCallBack onDataCallBack;

    public void setOnDataSet(OnDataSet onDataSet) {
        this.onDataSet = onDataSet;
    }

    public void setOnDataCallBack(OnDataCallBack onDataCallBack) {
        this.onDataCallBack = onDataCallBack;
    }

    private FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase;

    public HandleData() {
        firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    }

    public void putData(String specificNode, Pin pin){
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("path/to/node/").child(specificNode);
        databaseReference.setValue(pin).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                if(onDataSet != null){
                    onDataSet.onSucess();
                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                if(onDataSet != null){
                    onDataSet.onFailed(e.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void readData(String specificNode){
        DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference("path/to/node/").child(specificNode);
        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    int initCount = 0;
                    int totalCount = (int) dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
                    ArrayList<Pin> pins = new ArrayList<>();
                    for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        initCount = initCount +1;
                        Pin pin = snapshot.getValue(Pin.class);
                        pins.add(pin);
                        if(initCount == totalCount){
                            if(onDataCallBack != null){
                                onDataCallBack.onSuccess(pins);
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }else{
                    if(onDataCallBack != null){
                        onDataCallBack.onFailed("no data found in database");
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                if(onDataCallBack != null){
                    onDataCallBack.onFailed(databaseError.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public class Pin{

        private String about;
        private String imgUrl;
        private String lat;
        private String lng;

        public Pin() {

        }

        public Pin(String about, String imgUrl, String lat, String lng) {
            this.about = about;
            this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
            this.lat = lat;
            this.lng = lng;
        }

        public String getAbout() {
            return about;
        }

        public void setAbout(String about) {
            this.about = about;
        }

        public String getImgUrl() {
            return imgUrl;
        }

        public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
            this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
        }

        public String getLat() {
            return lat;
        }

        public void setLat(String lat) {
            this.lat = lat;
        }

        public String getLng() {
            return lng;
        }

        public void setLng(String lng) {
            this.lng = lng;
        }
    }

    public interface OnDataSet{
        void onSucess();
        void onFailed(String error);
    }

    public interface OnDataCallBack{
        void onSuccess(ArrayList<Pin> pins);
        void onFailed(String error);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try that in  a moment and tell you if it's working :D

Comment: So i tried your way but i don't really know how everything works

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here

```
item.put("Longitude ", lon);
```

change it to this

```
item.put("Longitude", lon);
```

as that is pushing the key value with " " at your Firebase structure and thats why you can't fetch that value, since a Map needs a Key - Value pair to work and it can't find out the Longitude data.

Also, after changing this, you will need to push new values and delete the ones at your database that are wrong

The logcat exception is pointing out right here

```
double longitude = Double.parseDouble(map.get("Longitude"));
```

with this

> java.util.Map has generic type parameters

[image]

Now , fetching the data.

As I understand, you need to press a button and fetch all LatLang from that node at firebase, let say you have the button **Poubelle** that gets all the latitude and longitude from that node, that can be done in this way.

```
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        DatabaseReference mPoubelleRef = mDatabase.child("Pins").child("Poubelle");

        BtnPoubelle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                mPoubelleRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
          @Override
          public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                 Map<String, String> map = snapshot.getValue(Map.class);
                            double latitude = Double.parseDouble(map.get("Latitude"));
                            double longitude = Double.parseDouble(map.get("Longitude"));

               //or get the data with a model (is the same thing as above)
               YourModel model = snapshot.getValue(YourModel.class);
               double latitude = model.getLatitude();
               double longitude = model.getLongitude();

               }
          }

          @Override
          public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
          }
        });
        }
```

**Before retrieving the data**, first delete the nodes with

> "Longitude " :

or it will fail each time when it tries to get your data.

Comment: If that worked can you mark the answer as correct ? Thanks and have a nice weekend